# Is there a simple kotlin compiler out there for windows without extra bloated IDEs?

Tags: windows, kotlin, command-line-interface

I have tried the download folder for [kotlininc,](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) and did everything the instructions said. And I'm still getting an error saying:
error: `Could not find or load main class org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main`

Is there a lite weight simple kotlin compiler for windows which is easy to install?
something like javac
or g++
etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want an IDE, I would recommend using a [build tool](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/build-tools.html). Kotlin supports Ant, Maven, and Gradle.

Of course, using the plain `kotlinc` [command-line compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) is the simplest, but you already linked to it. If you need help figuring out what you're doing wrong with that, create a new question and explain/show what you've tried.